# AutoPsy зависает на шаге 'Starting Modules"

Tags: linux, runtime, autopsy

Во время работы сдох диск. На нем были важные файлы. Решил попытаться восстановить.

Установка autopsy производилась как со snap-пакета, так и методом сборки. В обоих случаях ситуция одинаковая:

В процессе запуска Autopsy зависает на пункте "Starting modules" и висит так бесконечно долго.

Ошибок при запуске не видно. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

[image: пример того, кок отображается]

Comment: Я бы на твоём месте снял дамп через Linux LiveCD, где есть `ddrescue`. А уже потом - насиловал бы его прогами по восстановлению. Если винт сдох множественные обращения к нему жизни чтоно не продлевают.